# Java resultset getblob and getobject difference

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am having a problem with writing / reading an `BufferedImage` java dataType here. When writing it seems to have no problem with the inserted data, but when reading, i have a problem using "getObject" method from java ResultSet (For some particular reason, the method must be `getObject`, so i can read any type of data, and convert it after). When I am inserting BufferedImage dataType into mysql I am using inputStream and it has like 42559 at the byte array's length, but I am reading it using `getObject` the length is not 42559 anymore it's size turned into 42586, so I can not read it back using "ImageIO.read" method (It returns null)

Here is my insert code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write((BufferedImage) vals[i], "jpg", baos);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ps.setBinaryStream(i + 1, is);
```

Here is my read Code:

```
Object set = rs.getObject(i + 1);
```

and Here is my convert to BufferedImage code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
o.writeObject(set);
o.flush();
byte res[] = b.toByteArray();
o.close();
b.close();

System.out.println("Cek variabel: " + set.getClass() + "-" + res.toString() + "-" + res.length);
Blob blob = KubraLib.Conn.ConnSelect.getMySQLConn().createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, res);
System.out.println("Cek variabel: " + blob.toString());

InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
System.out.println("Cek variabel: " + is.toString());

bi = ImageIO.read(is);
System.out.println("Cek hasil: " + bi.toString()); <-- Returns java.lang.NullPointerException

is.close();
```

Any help would be appreciated :) . And im relatively new with Stack Overflow, if there's any mistake in this post, i apologize :))

Comment: Did you try `bi = rs.getBinaryStream(i);` instead of using `rs.getObject`?

Comment: No, but i tried using rs.getBlob(i) instead, and it worked. But as i said in my Question, i gotta use rs.getObject(i) for application standart reason. And it seems to have different binary values... And so i need to know how can i read an image using getObject...